# Two optional values in the attribute of the helper methods in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a helper method for generating a `li` content tag with a link

```
def method1(attribute,path,classname={},id={})
  content_tag(:li, link_to(attribute, path,:class => classname),:id => id)
end
```

I am calling the helper method like

```
<%= method1("BLOGS",blogs_path,"","blog1")%>
```

In the above case I gave an empty string for class as there is no need for class here, but other places need that.

But if I use an empty string for class , then `"blog1"` becomes the class ..

How can I resolve this?

I am working on rails 2.3.11

Comment: why not set an options hash so you can optionally add class or id whenever you need it? see the documentation and source code for the form helpers and you can copy the methods there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [options hashes](http://blog.ethanvizitei.com/2010/11/options-hash-classic-ruby-pattern.html). This is used just about everywhere in Rails and is perfect for handling clunky method invocations like that.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the other answers. Your method definition should be more like

```
def method1(attr, path, options={})
    content_tag(:li, link_to(attribute, path,:class => options[:classname]),:id => options[:id]) 
end
```

Then you can specify what you want to pass. On the downside, i seem to remember that rails sets the classname to the id if there is no classname passed in